# Dependency objects MySQL

Tags: mysql

Advise the GUI tool for viewing dependent object database MySQL.

for example:

```
USE db;

CREATE TABLE t1(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `column` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX id (id)
);

CREATE TABLE t2(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `column` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX FK_t2_t1_id (`column`),
  CONSTRAINT FK_t2_t1_id FOREIGN KEY (`column`)
  REFERENCES t1 (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE t3(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `column` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX FK_t3_t1_id (`column`),
  CONSTRAINT FK_t3_t1_id FOREIGN KEY (`column`)
  REFERENCES t1 (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    db.t1;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to see which objects refer to the table t1.
In this example it are t2, t3 and procedure1

Comment: Did you ever found a tool that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't all that clear, but it sounds like you're looking for some sort of GUI tool to do data modeling with MySQL. If that's correct, try looking at [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

Comment: I've looked at the MySQL Workbench, but there is no such functionality. maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: In MySQL Workbench under the Database menu, there's a "Reverse Engineer" option you can use to build an EER model of your database. Wouldn't that show you this?

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely what you are looking for. The information can be found in information_schema.

```
     SELECT pk.constraint_schema       AS PKDatabaseName
          , pk.table_name              AS PKObjectName
          , fk_cols.column_name        AS PKColumnName
          , fk_cols.referenced_table_schema AS FKDatabaseName
          , fk_cols.referenced_table_name   AS FKObjectName
          , fk_cols.referenced_column_name  AS FKColumnName
          , pk.constraint_name         AS ConstraintName
          , fk_cols.ordinal_position   AS ColumnIdx
       FROM information_schema.table_constraints pk
 INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage  fk_cols
         ON pk.constraint_schema = fk_cols.table_schema
        AND pk.table_name        = fk_cols.table_name
        AND pk.constraint_name   = fk_cols.constraint_name
      WHERE pk.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```